# Numpy - Change value of masked constants

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large 3 dimensional `MaskedArray` and I'm applying a function like `numpy.mean` or `numpy.std` to one of its axes.

The problem is that at some places in the array, all elements that are being fed to the mean function are masked and when I save everything to file (NetCDF format) I get **0s**.

How can I turn all those values from masked (`MaskedConstant` type) to the fill value I originally had? I am looking for either some magical way that doesn't involve `if` statements or at least a very fast way of doing it, because the dataset is very large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
x[x.mask] = fill_value
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#accessing-only-the-valid-entries